# Django rest swagger document shows choose file as string

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-swagger

I am creating simple swagger documentation with django rest framework, django rest swagger.

```
Python: 3.6
Django: 3.0.3
django-rest-swagger: 2.2.0
djangorestframework: 3.11.0
```

Here is **Models.py**

```
class Image(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos', null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'image'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file.name
```

and I created **serializers.py**

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('id', 'file', 'created_at')
```

Also here is **image_view.py**

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.parsers import FormParser, MultiPartParser, FileUploadParser

from api.serializers import ImageSerializer
from api.models import Image


class ImageView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser, )

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
           Image Moodel
           ---
           parameters:
               - name: file
                 type: file
           responseMessages:
               - code: 201
                 message: Created
       """
        file = request.data.get('file')
        image = Image(file=file, name=file.name)
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Image upload shows as string.

[image]

How can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Quickly consulting the Swagger documentation, it looks like depending on which OpenAPI version you're targeting this is the correct behavior. Version 3 of the OpenAPI specifications does not support concept of a file type whereas v2 does have a concept of a file format. This makes sense considering the RFC that defines JSON, [RFC7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#page-5), has a limited list of value types that are considered as part of valid JSON.

More information can be  found [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/)

Addendum: I can't speak directly for the framework you're using to generate the documentation but for image/file upload, the `format` attribute can be used to specify how the file is suppose to be uploaded, i.e. binary, base64 encoded. You can find more information [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/file-upload/) regarding File Upload and the OpenAPI specification

Looking into your framework documentation, it also appears that it targets the older Swagger 1.2/OpenAPI v2 spec in which case this is still the correct behavior as detailed in the OpenAPI v2 on [data types](https://swagger.io/specification/v2/#data-types)

Answer (score 0):

You can Set your parsers like this:

```
parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser)
```

Then in the swagger you can have file upload button

Answer (score 0):

Add the following at the end of **settings.py**:

```py
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'COMPONENT_SPLIT_REQUEST': True,
}
```

Also in Swagger UI, make sure you change the content-type from **application/json** to **multipart/form-data** and click **Try it out**. The upload button will apppear.